# How to extract number from string and assign it into a variable

Tags: php

I have a String,

```
`$str = 'Phone Number 02123456 an Bambang Pamungkas RpTag:749570 RpAdm:2500 Total Rp 750.250';`
```

i want to extract each number into a variable.

e.g

```
$Phone_num = ‘02123456';
$RpTag = ‘749570’;
$RpAdm = ‘2500’;
$Total = ‘750250’;
```

I want the result like as shown above, how do i do that?

P.S sorry for my bad english

Comment: What string processing functions have you tried? Which of them have you found? Try to get an overview of what PHP offers, maybe one of the tools fits your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_match_all` here:

```php
$str = 'Phone Number 02123456 an Bambang Pamungkas RpTag:749570 RpAdm:2500 Total Rp 750.250';
preg_match_all("/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/", $str, $nums);
print_r($nums[0]);  // [02123456, 749570, 2500 750.250]
```

Note that I don't see any point or advantage to having each number in a separate variable.  If you really need that, then just iterate the `$nums` array output from above and make the separate assignments.